# Internal vs Extenal use of parameterized sql command

Tags: sql, sql-injection

In terms of SQL injection, I understand why parameterizing a string parameter is important. But is it acceptable or justified to not parameterize a command when working with let's say a database dependent software for a company which is primarily targeted on internal use rather than that of external influence?

Comment: Two words to keep in mind... Disgruntled Employee

Answer (score 3):

Like I always say, [you need it not for Bobby Tables but for Sarah O'Hara](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection#whatis). It is **syntactically correct SQL query** what you have from the prepared statement in the first place, while protection is just a side effect. It's the destination that matters. You have to mind the SQL query where your data goes into. While the data source should the last thing to consider.

Besides, I don't see a point in bargaining. What you're trying to buy for yourself here? Are parameters *that* hard for you? Well, blame the library you are using. A properly implemented a parametrized query is a *simplest* way to run a query.